# Rails Combine Carrierwave Uploads into Downloadable Zip File

Tags: windows-7, ruby-on-rails-3.1, compression, download, carrierwave

I have several files that were uploaded and files are grouped in a folder. I have a mass download button that will download all of the files in the folder. When they click the button to download, it will run this method.

```
  def download_multiple
    @odocument = Odocument.find(params[:id])
    @files = Redocument.find(:all, :conditions => {:odocument_id => @odocument.id})
    t = Tempfile.new('tmp-zip-' + request.remote_ip)
    Zip::ZipOutputStream.open(t.path) do |zos|
      @files.each do |file|
        zos.put_next_entry(File.basename(file.redocument.url))
        zos.print IO.read(file.redocument.url)
      end
    end
    filename = @odocument.document_name + ".zip"
    t.close    

    send_file t.path, :type => "application/zip", :filename => filename     
  end
```

This will download and create the ZIP file and when using WinRAR or 7Zip it will extract the files and I can successfully open/edit them. However, when using Windows XP/Vista/7 internal zip extractor, it will generate an *unspecified error 0x80004005*.

Despite being able to download and open the files using WinRAR or 7Zip, I don't really see this as an effective solution. Any idea how I can change the download_multiple method so that it will allow Windows to open the ZIP file without any compression software outside of what comes with Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A recent gem update has fixed this issue.